# how to hide underline in editText when input type is text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

how to hide underline when entering text in edit text?
 given `inputType = text`, I'm able to see the line coming under words and giving space and entering the next word line in the first word disappears. Is this a default behaviour? when inputType is given as `android:inputType="text|textVisiblePassword"`
 when entering characters line is not visible can any one suggest me `text|textVisiblePassword` is correct to use for edit text to make the line disappear?

Comment: That is probably because of autocorrect.

Comment: Are you using this     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
??

Answer (score 0):

android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable a spelling checker in `edittext` using this code :

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: you are getting the issue in one specific device or in all devices

Comment: i m trying in samsung device

Answer (score 0):

From xml, disable a spelling checker in `edittext`:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

**OR**

Programmatically you can use:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Comment: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" not working still it show underline

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code in EditText XML.

```
    android:background="@null"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iseSr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in XML :

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: it should be single line